# What is the easiest way to evaluate k-means clustering?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I did clustering with k-means, but I haven't complete my project, now I have to evaluate the result of the k-means clustering, and I want to do that with the easiest way. does anyone have any suggestions and example?. Help me please. Thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to **print the sum of squares** and compare with other tools.

Since k-means heuristically minimizes this value, it should be close to the ideal value. If the value is much higher, there is a bug.

There is no "true" solution in clustering. It's successful, if you discovered new knowledge, not just because you optimized some statistic.

Comment: have you any example to do the sum of squares calculation?

Comment: Sum of squares is usually reported on most statistical tools. What did you use in your case?

Comment: Sum of squares arises naturally when computing k-means. Just compute it while running k-means, *don't recompute it*.